# Почему перед союзом "и" ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**Нагромождённые друг на друга ломаные ледяные глыбы, и длинные полярные ночи, и свирепые буранные шквалы, и непрестанные морозы.**

Просьба указать правило по справочнику Розенталя.

Comment: Справочник можно найти в Сети.

Comment: Вопрос слишком прост, уровня домашнего задания. А их тут обычно не делают. Вы сами-то как считаете, должна там быть запятая?!

Answer (score 2):

Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами и…и, да…да, ни…ни, или…или, либо…либо, то…то, не то…не то и др., ставится запятая: В этом возгласе было и восхищение, и благодарность, и любовь (Пауст.);

См.: [Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация. Д. Э. Розенталь.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

Answer (score 1):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами: Листья в поле пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; Лён, и полотна, и пряжу несут; А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (М. Г.); Отрывистый и ломаный звук метался, и прыгал, и бежал куда-то в сторону от других (Андр.); Иные хозяева вырастили уже вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Ф); Только мальвы, да ноготки, да кручёный паныч цвели кое-где по дворам (Пан.); Весь вечер Ленский был рассеян, то молчалив, то весел вновь (П.).

Answer (score 0):

Если число однородных членов больше двух, а союз **и** повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между ними всеми, например:

*В лесу одному **шумно, и жутко, и весело*** (Фет).
*Принесли букет чертополоха и на стол поставили, и вот передо мной **пожар, и суматоха, и** огней багровых **хоровод*** (Забол.).
*И сегодня рифма поэта – **ласка, и лозунг, и штык, и кнут*** (М.).

В Вашем предложении эта комбинация (союзного и бессоюзного сочетания однородных членов) присутствует:

Нагромождённые друг на друга ломаные ледяные **глыбы, и** длинные полярные **ночи, и** свирепые буранные **шквалы, и** непрестанные **морозы**.

[**§87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами (п.5)**](https://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik-scibook/odnorodnyie-chlenyi-soedinennyie-37383.html)